# Setting a custom place holder image in twig/timber theme

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, custom-wordpress-pages, timber

So I am having a `twig/timber` issue where I have a difficult time getting a placeimage set, here is what I have so far:

```
{% set defaultimg = site.theme.link ~ '/images/placeimage.png' %}
```

and then later in my code I have:

```
<img src="{{ post.thumbnail.src | default(defaultimg) | resize(360, 240)}}" class="card-img-top">
```

post.thumbnail.src pulls in the images just fine but if no featured Img in attached to the post I want the `defaultimg` to pull in an image from my custom themes image folder. But currently this is outputting a really erroneous url of:

```
<img src="https://toolcart.local/wp-contentC:\Users\User\Local Sites\toolcart\app\public\wp-content\themes\toolcart-theme\images/placeimage-360x240-c-default.png" class="card-img-top">
```

However a `{{defaultimg}}` outputs the image url correctly.

```
https://toolcart.local/wp-content/themes/toolcart-theme/images/placeimage.png
```

I am not sure what to try next?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an issue with the way `twig/timber` defines paths!!! Supper weird way of doing things which adds unnecessary complexity to a project.

That being said, according to [their documentation](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/filters/#relative), you could add a filter called `relative` to the end of your `defaultimg` variable which converts an absolute URL into a relative one which eventually outputs the correct path to your default image.

So your code would be something like this:

- Defining the path to your default image:

```php
{% set defaultimg = Image(site.theme.link ~ '/images/placeimage.png') | relative %}
```

**NOTE:**
The `| relative` filter will do the trick here.

- Calling it in the image source attribute:

```html
<img src="{{ post.thumbnail.src | default(defaultimg) | resize(360, 240)}}" class="card-img-top">
```

I just tested the code and it worked fine! Le me know if you could get it to work too!

Comment: I want to thank-you for taking the time to explain this for me. I do have a followup question: It seems that some times the `| resize(360, 240)` just totally messes up the url to the default image such as this example here: [ImageLink](https://prnt.sc/1x7h7v2) would you happen to have any thoughts on why this would happen?

Comment: No problem! Happy to help! Make sure that use the code I provided you with. The code I provided works fine on my end. [Here's a screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R88Ol.png). Both `featured image` and `custom placeholder image` work fine!